Understanding Time Complexity of Geometric Progression Series
According to my professor, the following code has a time complexity of O(N), but I don't understand why time complexity is so.
int sum = 0;
for (int i=1; i<n; i=i*3) {
    for (int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
        sum++;
    }
}

From how I see it, the outer loop is O(logN) and the inner loop is O(i*N).
So shouldn't the time complexity be O(i*N) * O(logN) = NlogN?

The inner loop will perform the following number of iterations:
1 for the 1st outer iteration
3 for the 2nd outer iteration
9 for the 3rd outer iteration
...
~n for the last outer iteration.
I.e. the inner loop will totally run 1+3+9+ ... + ~n times.
This is a geometric series with O(logn) elements, and the sum of it is O(n).
This is because the gemeral sum of a geometric series starting with a1, witha ratio of r and with x elements is:
Sx = a1 * (1 - r^x) / (1 - r)

If you use 1 for a1, 3 for r, and logn for x, you will get:
Slogn = 1 * (1 - 3^logn) / (1 - 3)

And since 3^logn is O(n), the whole expression is O(n).

In your code, the outer loop runs about (log n) times because i multiplies by 3 each time. For each of these runs, the inner loop runs i times, where i gets bigger with each loop.
When you add up all the work done by the inner loop across all outer loop iterations, it adds up to something proportional to n. So, your professor is correct, the total time complexity of your code is indeed O(n).

As you are moving, multiplying by three, I would go for the following approach:
Try with the values n=729 (3^6), n=6561 (3^8), n=59049 (3^10) and n=531441 (3^12), and put a writeln("something"); next to the command sum++.
Count the number of times something is written on your screen.
If the complexity is O(N), that amount will be multiplied by 9 every time. If the complexity is O(N log(N)), the quotiënt will be higher.
